# Counting through the iterations in blade (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I was wondering whether I could do an if statement for each iteration through the array. This is so that I can punctuate each user with either a ',' or an '&' depending on how many users.

```
@foreach ($copy as $user => $value) 
@if ($user == 0)
{{$value->username}}
@endif
@if ($user == 1)
,&nbsp;{{$value->username}}
@endif
@if ($user == 2)
,&nbsp;{{$value->username}}
@endif
@if ($user == 3)
&&nbsp;{{$value->username}}
@endif
@endforeach
```

The code above punctuates correctly if there are 4 users but what if I have less than 4. How would I move the '&' to the 3rd user if there were 3 users for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with issues such as this, try to find the most optimal solution. In this case you can determine that you need the comma in all but two places and the ampersand in one. So instead of having a condition for each array index, you should place one for commas and one for the ampersand:

```php
@foreach ($copy as $user => $value) 
    {{$value->username}}

    // Place commas after all but the last two items
    @if ($user < count($copy) - 2)
        ,
    @endif

    // Place an ampersand before the last item
    @if ($user == count($copy) - 2)
        &amp;
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This will work with a list of any size.